# C# pass by reference vs value issue?

Tags: c#, reference

I am getting a `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow` error and I am not sure why. Firstly, I have a field `private Summary summary;` and then I assign it inside a method that uses the out keyword like the following.

```
int id = 5; 
if (getSummary(out Summary result, in id)) {
     processSummaryBindingSource2.DataSource = result; // This sets the data in the gui
     this.summary = result;
}
```

Then after this is called I know the Summary is not null and at this point the data will be displayed in my GUI. But then my next call tries to use summary, but I get the error I quoted at the top.

```
if(useSummary(summary, out PEFile outputFile)) { // The useSummary method is located in another class so I pass in the summary field (PEFile is a custom class that has nothing to do with the normal File class)
    // It does not reach here before crashing
}

public bool useSummary(Summary summary, out PEFile outputFile)
{
    IntPtr basePointer = (IntPtr) summary.MainModuleBase;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = ReadProcessStruct<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(summary.ProcessId, basePointer);
    outputFile = default(PEFile);
    // More code follows but I never get an error originating from anything in this method
```

Now I am new to C# but I have programmed in Java for many years, so I am thinking it's an issue with passing in `summary` as a value instead of by its reference because I have no other explanation. In Java `result` will have its virtual address (which points to the start of the object) saved on the stack while the object's actual fields will be saved in the heap. Then when no other context contains a reference to this heap object it will be eligible for garbage collection. So, when you do `this.summary = result;` it will copy the virtual address that points to the start of the object's memory in heap to the global field `summary`. Then when I call `useSummary(summary)` it will pass in the pointer to the Summary object into the useSummary method.

Now, I am not sure what is going on here with C# I hope someone can explain to me the issue here, but I suspect it's trying to pass in the value of `summary` which of course contains way more bytes than a simple pointer, so it throws an overflow exception. Not sure if I am right but I can't think or another explanation but I appreciate anyone who can help me understand the differences here with C# so I can avoid this in the future and get my code working.

Comment: If Summary is a class, then `useSummary(summary)` is "pass by reference", it wont create a copy. Can you post the `useSummary` code?

Comment: @Loocid Yea, let me do that but I am getting a "Unhandled exception" warning that pops up over my Gui and the stack trace never contains anything after so I assume it has nothing to do with what is in the method unless I dont understand how those pop-up notifications work.

Comment: Based on exception you are getting, your code is receiving the object, but have issues when calculating something in `useSummary`. Probably a multiplication resulting too big number to handle.

Comment: @Orifjon oh for real? I thought the topmost component in the exception denotes the code that is causing the issue. Because otherwise theres no real point in giving a stack trace if it is not giving any relevant data. I mean just crashing would get me to the same spot I am now.

Comment: @UnSure - BTW, C# & Java have different naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

This was not a pass by reference / pass by value error. The issue was I thought that because the exception happened before it got into the method that the issue must not be with the code inside the method. So, it seems the C# handles errors differently from Java but that being said there was not actually any errors with my code. Instead, I compiled my code for "Any CPU" since that is default. I then used another program to view all running processes on my computer and saw my program was running in x86 which changes the size of `IntPtr` inside C# thus resulting in an overflow error. I changed it to x64 and everything works perfectly thank you all for the comments that lead me to think about this.

Comment: *Primitive* sizes are the same for all architectures in C#, but `IntPtr` very much is not.  It will be 32-bit on x86 and 64-bit on x64.

Comment: @Powerlord That makes a lot of sense considering the first line of that method used IntPtr. I updated my answer to reflect what you pointed out.